# Spring security - can not get to the login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This is my spring security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select nickname,password, true from client where nickname=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
        http.formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .loginPage("/login");
    }
}
```

When I am trying to open my webpage I get this error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or
>   refusing to accept cookies.

When I delete configure method everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration problem.

You have a pattern for intercept-url `"/*"` and `ROLE_USER'` what means that if a user is not authorized - it will be redirected to `login` page.

Application Context resolves `login` page and finds out that `/login` page matches `"/*"` pattern, that should be intercepted and authenticated for `ROLE_USER`. A user without authentication, evidently, doesn't have `ROLE_USER` and redirected to `/login` page and all over again.

Allowing unathorized users acces the login page should do the trick:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/*")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
    http.formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .loginPage("/login");
}
```

Pay attention to the order. More specific filters should be written first, or they will be 'shadowed' by wider filters and ignored.

`permitAll()` could be applied to `login` page directly omitting first matcher, as was already proposed:

```
.loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

Comment: Instead of adding a further pattern, I would recommend to use the convienence method `.permitAll()` of `formLogin()`, see TwiN's answer.

Answer (score 2):

After

```
    .loginPage("/login")
```

you should add

```
    .permitAll();
```

Doing the above should fix your issues. As for why that was happening, it's because your `loginPage` requires the user to be authenticated, which causes Spring to redirect the user to the `loginPage`, and it loops from there.
Firefox is just nice enough to stop the request when it detects that behavior.

I also suggest that you use `.anyRequest()` instead of `.antMatchers("/*")`.

The final result should look like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```